# IIS Express expecting IntegratedWindowsAuthentication, how do I enable Anonymous Authentication?

Tags: wcf, authentication, iis-express

I've got a WCF service with this configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

It used to work with no problems but something must have changed because when I try to run it now I get this error:

> The authentication schemes configured on the host
>   ('IntegratedWindowsAuthentication') do not allow those configured on
>   the binding 'BasicHttpBinding' ('Anonymous').

I've tried deleting the IIS Express configuration files in the hope that it would reset itself to its default configuration (which I would assume includes Anonymous Authentication) but I still get the same error.

Is the error somewhere else, do I need to explicitly reconfigure IIS Express, or am I missing something else completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it.  Even though I reset the IIS Express configuration, for some reason it still disabled Anonymous Authentication on this application.  Once I scrolled down to the bottom of the configuration file I found the following entry:

```
<location path="MyApplication">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

I enabled Anonymous Authentication the application worked.